# Callback not running second function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I tried to research callbacks before asking this - but something in what I'm writing is not working. I define the functions first, and then tell them to run onload. getelements() runs fine on its own.

I am trying to load the elements, then count them, to be used in math to display one of random index.

```
    function getelements() {
     jQuery('#testimonial').load('http://www.example.com .testimonial');

 }

 function countelements() {
     var elements = jQuery('div.testimonial').length;
     console.log(elements);
 }

 window.onload = function () {
     getelements(function () {

         countelements();
     });
 }
```

Comment: Typo? "http://www.example.com .testimonial"

Comment: You could **actually** `return` the result of the `.load()` call from your `getelements` function, and then in your `window.onload` handler, use `getelements().done(countelements);`

Comment: @sethflowers No, that's the syntax for `.load()`. You can provide a selector after the URL (yes, in the same string), that only loads those elements. http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: @Ian - interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing a callback to `getelements` but your function doesn't use it.

Change your `getElements` function to

```
function getelements(callback) {
   jQuery('#testimonial').load('http://www.example.com .testimonial', callback);
}
```

JQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function will call the callback once the distant resource is loaded.

Comment: YES! This worked absolutely perfectly. Thank you.
So just to clarify - what I was missing from the callback was to just set callback in the function?

Does that basically tell the browser "but wait, there's more"?

Comment: The main problem was in fact that you weren't giving the callback to jquery's load function. Some functions throw an error when you don't provide the parameters, some other, for example most jquery functions, simply assume you don't need them (i.e. you have nothing to do after the resource is loaded).

Comment: Thanks, I'll read into it some more - but the application is up and running. Thanks!